# INSERT or UPDATE using IF-ELSE php MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
DONOR
donor-nic----username-----status
111----------ali----------available
222---------usman--------notavailable
```

another is

```
DONATION
donation_id------donor_nic-----date---
1----------------111----------2012/03/04
2---------------111-----------2012/06/07
3----------------111---------2012/07/08
4----------------222---------2012/03/03
```

now i want to update the date if it is already exits corresponding to donor_nic
if date does not exists i want to insert that new date,.

i am using this query to fetching all dates according to corresponding donor_nic

```
SELECT donor.donor_nic, donation.lastdonationdate
FROM donor
JOIN donation ON donor.donor_nic = donation.donor_nic
WHERE username = 'ali'
GROUP BY donation.lastdonationdate
```

now this query works in phpmyadmin.. but when i use this in my page.. it does not match date.. i am matching date like this

```
   $sql= SELECT donor.donor_nic, donation.lastdonationdate
    FROM donor
    JOIN donation ON donor.donor_nic = donation.donor_nic
    WHERE username = 'ali'
    GROUP BY donation.lastdonationdate

$res=mysql_query($sql, $con);

if($res == $date)
{
echo "update";
}
else
{
echo "insert";
}
```

but this thing didnt work.. may be i am making mistake in conditional (if-else) statment..  plz help me what should i do..
thanks in advance

Comment: "Didn't work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. Have you tried using a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: no.. i am new in php .. i dun know about "debugger".. my query proper runs in phpmyadmin but when i run my page it always return "update" .. even if i enter new date

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `$res` variable is a result set object and not a string or date value.  Also where did you define `$date`?

If you want to get an individual result from your query, use:

```
$res=mysql_result(mysql_query($sql, $con),0,1);
```

This will return the second column from the first row of your result, ( that is what the `,0,1` define as arguments to the `mysql_result` function) which I think is the date you are looking for.

check the docs for mysql_result: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

mysql_query always returns an array, not a particular value.  Assuming your `$date` varialble is in the right format the above should work.

**EDIT**

Also you need to change the way you define `$SQL`, put quotes around it, like this:

```
$sql= "SELECT donor.donor_nic, donation.lastdonationdate
    FROM donor
    JOIN donation ON donor.donor_nic = donation.donor_nic
    WHERE username = 'ali'
    GROUP BY donation.lastdonationdate";
```

Comment: $sql= SELECT donor.donor_nic, donation.lastdonationdate
    FROM donor
    JOIN donation ON donor.donor_nic = donation.donor_nic
    WHERE username = 'ali'
    GROUP BY donation.lastdonationdate

$res=mysql_query($sql, $con);

if($res == $date)
{
echo "update";
}
else
{
echo "insert";
}

Comment: i put       $res=mysql_result(mysql_query($sql, $con),0,1);           but it again return "update" even i enter new date,, and i have declared variable date ... $date= $_REQUEST['lastdonationdate']   ::(

Comment: you should debug your code, put `echo $res.' -- '.$date;` on the line after `$res=mysql_result(mysql_query($sql, $con),0,1);` and it will display the two values you are comparing.   You will also be able to see if you are getting the correct data from the server.

Comment: Oh, also it looks like you aren't putting your `$SQL` string in quotes, see my updated answer.

Comment: i have put strings.. i also put code u mentioned above.. it shows only 1 date i-e the first one in the record.. if u see ablove code.. it shows   """---2012/03/04...."""  and my new date.. it does not show all dates and still return "updated"...  :( @jeffery

Comment: Oh I see you want to show all the dates, for each row of the database?  I thought you just wanted the first line?  Also please post the exact output from your script, so I can tell which dates correspond to which variable.

Comment: when a user(donor) enters the date according to his donor_nic.. if the date he entered alreday exists then just update that date.. if the date is new then insert the new date in donation table.. {now query query/code should be in this way that first get all the dates corresponding to dono_nic and then check new date with all existing dates... } if it matches.. it will update... if it doesnot match it will insert...

Comment: Well there is a simple query that does pretty much exactly what you are saying.  `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`, see the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html.  However you would have to set the `lastdonationdate` column as the primary key, and the information that you want to update would have have to be in the same table as your lastdonationdate column.  You can do it in code like you had before, but I need to output from the code to see why you aren't getting the right dates.

Comment: i cant make lastdonationdate as PK...  i just put new query {}SELECT COUNT(lastdonationdate) > 0
     FROM donation 
     WHERE donor_nic='".$rs."' AND lastdonationdate='".$dt."'";

Answer (score 0):

For the solution I have set to variables - the nic to test again and the date to test against, set at the top of the script.
Has been edited where I felt needed but basically the script sets to variables (which you can update to be retrieved via form or whatever).
Then builds the first mysql query, which will return an array of the required nic and date.
A loop within a loop is required to grab the values returned. 
The values (and keys) and stored in there own arrays, which we then search upon using our pre determined variables, and you are informed if the insert/update was successful.
Obviously requires work, but gets the job done.

```
$nic = "111";
$date2add = "14/12/13";

$sql="SELECT donor.donor-nic, donation.date
FROM donor
JOIN donation ON donor.donor-nic = donation.donor-nic
WHERE username = 'ali'
GROUP BY donation.date";

$res=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

//may need error checking here to verify that $res has data.
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//initiate a loop to select values
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //initiate a loop to store values into an array so that we can compare against later.
foreach ($row as $keys => $val) {
    echo "<br />$keys...$val<br />";
    $keysar[] = $keys;
    $valsar[] = $val;
}
}


 //using values above we will search the $valsar (created in the above loop) for $date2add (the date req. to be searched against)
if (in_array($date2add, $valsar) == $date2add) {
$sql = "UPDATE donation SET date = '$date2add' WHERE nic='$nic'";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or trigger_error("Query: $sql\n<br />MySQL   Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
if ($res) {
    echo "Record  updated correctly<br />";
} else {
    echo "failed  to update<br />";
}
} else {
  //these variables will have to set from somewhere if the script will insert correctly.
$sql = 'INSERT INTO donation ("$donation_id", "$nic", "$date")';
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) == 1) {
    echo "it inserted correctly<br />";
} else {
    echo "failed  to insert<br />";
}
}
```